# "Given are ..." or " ... are given" - what is the difference between these two?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, passive-voice

Also I want to know what voice was used in "Given are ...". Was it passive voice?

Example:

- *Given are two tables referring to criminality in Britain.*

&

- *Two tables referring to criminality in Britain are given.*

Comment: The question would benefit from the addition of some examples.

Comment: Both your examples are passive voice. "Given are..." is rather uncommon, especially used in enunciations of problems that need to be solved.

Comment: I think you mean, by “given”, that they’re shown or displayed. “Given” can also introduce premises or definitions, such as “Given that a=b . . .

Comment: And by figures I assume you mean graphs or data plots.

Comment: Both versions are passive.  Putting the verb at the beginning of the sentence is a way of emphasising it.

Comment: It's just "stylised inversion" - usually done for literary / poetic effect. Compare ***Tender is the night*** as inverted from the default standard English Subject-Verb-Object sequence ***The night is tender***.

Comment: ... I'd say that 'stylised inversion', while carrying the risk of sounding rarefied, is sometimes used in an attempt not to sound stultifyingly mundane and/or to avoid a ridiculously delayed verb. 'The day is tomorrow!' / 'Two tables referring to the perceived increase in criminality among the voting public in Britain are given.'

Answer (score 0):

Both the sentences are in passive voice.These are two different ways of constructing a sentence. By placing the verb in the beginning of a sentence you are trying to draw the attention. While the second sentence sounds conventional, the first one is more on the artistic side.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Both are in passive voice.

*Given are two tables referring to criminality in Britain.* (emphasis)

*Two tables referring to criminality in Britain are given.* (usual)

Comment: Hello, Mohammed. I'd say this repeats Megha's answer so closely that it doesn't add a great deal.

Answer (score -2):

Both are correct:
The first would usually be found below a table with the meaning of The table that *has been* given above.

The second can be used above a table with the meaning of The table that *is* given below.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).